# how to utilize submodule without any modification in python?

Tags: git, python-3.x, git-submodules

I'm supposed to make two git repositories and make one of these a submodule. I have not to modify anything in the submodule. But, when I try to import something in the submodule, there are some path problem. The problem is as follows.

## Module 1 (git repository)

### layout

```
module
  |
  +--- __init__.py
  +--- model.py
  +--- utils.py
```

### in model.py

```
import utils

# blah, blah
```

## Module 2 (git repository)

The second module uses model.py the first module

### layout

```
module
  |
  +--- main.py
  +--- submodule (Module 1 repository)
```

### in main.py

```
import submodule.model

# blah, blah
```

## < command line >

```
~/module2$ python main.py
```

Then, There is a crash.

```
----> 1 import submodule.model
      2 
      3 # blah, blah

~/module2/submodule/model.py in <module>()
----> 1 import utils
      2
      3 # blah, blah
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

The "Module 1" is required not to be modified.
then, how can I use this submodule in the "Module 2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 all imports are absolute. Module1 must perform absolute import

```
import module1.utils
```

or relative import explicitly:

```
import .utils
```

It's a bug in Module1 and you should fix it.

If you still insist on using a buggy module, you can add Module1 to `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` so that `import utils` finds it in `sys.path`.